# Finding the bases for the eigenspace of the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Working through Anton's Linear Algebra textbook and one question asks for to find the characteristic equation, the eigenvalues, and bases for the eigenspaces of the matrix.

The given matrix is \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 &1
\end{bmatrix}

First, computing for the determinant using $\lambda I - A$, the characteristic equation I found was $ (\lambda - 1)^2=0$, thus $\lambda = 1$.

However, when trying to solve for the bases of the eigenspace, I'm left with the zero matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 &0
\end{bmatrix}$, which leaves me with nothing to work with seemingly. The solutions provided suggest the bases for the eigenspace is {${(1,0), (0,1)}$} and I was hoping someone might explain the logic behind that for me. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Getting a value that looks curious should not let you forget your original plan. You were establishing that matrix to compute its kernel (equivalently to set up a linear homogeneous system of equations to solve), so you get a system of trivially true equations. What is the space of solutions to the empty set of equations on a vector space? And what are the bases for that space of solutions?

Comment: The null space of zero matrix is $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the eigenspace. Any basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be a basis of eigenspace.

Comment: Thank you guys this makes a lot more sense now, I appreciate it